# Getting the whole field instead of iterating through

Tags: list, javascript

```
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Privacy Statements');

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="IsActive"/><Value Type="Integer">1</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="SortOrder"/></OrderBy></View></Query>');
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);


clientContext.load(collListItem);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)); 

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {

                        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

                        listTitle.push(oListItem.get_item('Title'));
                        listUrl.push(oListItem.get_item('PrivacyStatementUrls').get_url()); 

                    }
```

Is there anyway of getting the whole list of a column straight away instead of having to use the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SP.ListItem.fieldValues Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee548409%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to return a *collection of key/value pairs* containing the names and values for the fields of the list item.

Example

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle); 
var items = list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());

context.load(items);
context.executeQueryAsync(
function(){

  var rowsData = [];
  var e = items.getEnumerator();
  while (e.moveNext()) {
       var item = e.get_current();

       var values = item.get_fieldValues();
       rowsData.push(values);
   }

}, 
function(sender,args){
  console.log(args.get_message());    
});
```